# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

I am converting the uk date format string to US format to save this into database but it throw me error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
string dateString = "13/06/2011";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

I have also tried this but same exception.

```
DateTime aa = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Please let me know how can i convert uk format date in string to us date format.

Thanks.

Comment: Because month 13 doesn't exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified the wrong format. It should be `dd/MM/yyyy`:

```
var dateString = "13/06/2011";
var aa = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: This works for me but after conversion when i save it and convert it to UK it changes the months to days and days to months. in var dateString = "13/06/2011"; it is 13-june-2011 after saving and retreiving it shows 06/13/2011 but it should show 13/06/2011.

Comment: I have resolved this <br> var date = dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) with an en-GB culture works fine:

```
string dateString = "13/06/2011";

DateTime aa = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
// aa.Day == 13
// aa.Month == 6
// aa.Year == 2011

string result = aa.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
// result == "6/13/2011"
```

Comment: This works for me but after conversion when i save it and convert it to UK it changes the months to days and days to months. in var dateString = "13/06/2011"; it is 13-june-2011 after saving and retreiving it shows 06/13/2011 but it should show 13/06/2011.

Comment: I have resolved this <br> var date = dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dtString,
System.Threading.Tread.CurrentThread.CurrentCultur e.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: Using the current thread's culture doesn't help with parsing a value in en-UK format when the current culture is not en-UK.

Comment: You are right, my point was just to show him that he should use the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat, not only the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, ;)