# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

My code is:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myDate = Request.QueryString["period"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myDate))
        {
            myDate = myDate.Replace("!", ":");
        }
        DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan variable = dt2 - dt1;
        if (variable.TotalMinutes > 5)
        {
            Response.Write("Download time is expired now");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
        }



    }
```

and I'm getting error like:

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Comment: Coud you provide your string?

Comment: what is the value of `myDate`?

Comment: Value of myDate is  test.aspx?period=09/04/2013 10:41:45 AM'

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291816/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime?rq=1

Comment: Why have you made up your own encoding the `:`s in the URL parameter rather than using standard URL encoding/decoding?

Comment: http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=11/04/2013%201:02:11%20PM&ProductName=Otja

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method;

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/BWq8wD).

You can check more Custom Date formats from [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

since you have this date formatted like `09/04/2013 10:41:45 AM`

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

if `09` is day, change the pattern into `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`

For more information about Date and Time Format Strings,

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: just ask if you have further clarification.

Comment: @purvangpandya I suggest you check first and then do it, not vice versa.